# How to get info about just opened tab in playwright?

Tags: typescript, testing, playwright

I'm investigating playwright and I'm trying to switch or at least to get title of tab, which was opened. But list of pages doesn't contain newly opened tab. My code is a base test from docs.

```
test('homepage has title and links to intro page navigation', async ({ browser }) => {
    const context = await browser.newContext();
    const page = await context.newPage();

    await page.goto('https://playwright.dev/');

    // Expect a title "to contain" a substring.
    await expect(page).toHaveTitle(/Playwright/);

    // create a locator
    const getStarted = page.getByRole('link', { name: 'Get started' });
    const twitterLink = page.locator("//a[contains(@href, 'twitter')]");
    await twitterLink.click({ button: "middle" })
        
    const pages = context.pages();// Only one page is shown there.
    let firstPageName: string = await pages[0].title();
    let secondPageName: string = await pages[1].title();
```

[Browser looks like that after clicking the link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yDnSY.png)

I've tried approaches from here (https://playwright.dev/docs/pages#handling-new-pages), but I'm not sure they work for me. I just don't really understand why I don't see the new tab in my code.

I've seen this example in docs and I tried to ise it, but nothing happens.

```
// Get all new pages (including popups) in the context
context.on('page', async page => {
  await page.waitForLoadState();
  console.log(await page.title());
})
```

So I want to understand why

```
context.pages()
```

doesn't return newly opened tabs.

Comment: I've solved the problem by adding wait after middle mouse button click.

await new Promise(f => setTimeout(f, 5000));

But it's a bit strange as I had a breakpoint on line called context.pages() and I continued code run only after I saw that tab was opened. So for some reasons explicit wait works fine, but debug stop doesn't.

Is there a way to explain that?

Comment: I think it's related somehow to the way of adding these pages to the context. So when the application is stuck on a breakpoint, no action listeners work and even if a new page was opened, the next line of code which gets pages works faster than the action listener method which adds a new tab to the context object in a parallel thread.

I'm not sure as I'm not so familiar with the playwright yet, so I'd like someone more experienced to correct me.

Answer (score 2):

Look at working/tested example (clicking GitHub link on Playwright main page):

```js
test("verify link in new tab", async ({ page }) => {
  await page.goto("https://playwright.dev/");
  const newTabPromise = page.waitForEvent("popup");

  await page.getByRole("link", { name: "GitHub repository" }).click();
  const newTab = await newTabPromise;
  await newTab.waitForLoadState();

  await expect(newTab).toHaveURL("https://github.com/microsoft/playwright");
  await expect(newTab).toHaveTitle(
    "GitHub - microsoft/playwright: Playwright is a framework for Web Testing and Automation. It allows testing Chromium, Firefox and WebKit with a single API."
  );
});
```

docs: https://playwright.dev/docs/pages#handling-popups

Answer (score 0):

I made some changes to your code, when I print the length of tabs, the result is 2 so it captured the newly opened tab. The problem can be resolved by waiting new page loaded
`await tabs[1].waitForLoadState("load");` Hope that helps and suggestions are welcomed

```
  test("homepage has title and links to intro page navigation", async ({
    browser,
  }) => {
    const context = await browser.newContext();
    const page = await context.newPage();
    await page.goto("https://playwright.dev/");
    // Expect a title "to contain" a substring.
    await expect(page).toHaveTitle(/Playwright/);
    // create a locator
    //const getStarted = page.getByRole("link", { name: "Get started" });
    const twitterLink = page.locator("//a[contains(@href, 'twitter')]");
    await twitterLink.click({ button: "middle" });
    const [pages] = await Promise.all([page.context().waitForEvent("page")]);
    const tabs = pages.context().pages();
    console.log(tabs.length);
    await tabs[1].waitForLoadState("load");
    console.log("first" + (await tabs[0].title()));
    console.log("second" + (await tabs[1].title()));
  });
```

Comment: It's not really clear for me how is it possible to call waitForLoadState on undefined. As in my case there is only one item in this array.